# jquery. help me with getting a url for the image

Tags: jquery, image, src

i want to get the url for the image. For this i use this code

```
 $(function () {
     $('.li').mousedown(function (e) {
         if (e.which === 1) {
             $(".li:nth-child(n) a").attr('id');
             var clickId = this.id;
             var n = clickId - 1;
             var imageurl = $(".fadein img:eq(" + n + ")").attr("src");
             alert(imageurl);
         }
     });
 });
```

problem is next. slide show displays a second image. I click on the first position and i'm getting the current url of image which is displayed. How to get the url of first image ?

who knows!!!!!! why i don't get an url of the image by id?

Comment: Can you give some html of this script ?

Comment: Arclite, yes, of course. See the code below

Comment: you can't get an id of li element when you calling an inner anchor $(".li:nth-child(n) a").attr('id'); and the var id isn't defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
$(function () {
 $('.circle li').on('click',function (e) {
         var id = $(this).attr("id"); //this is the number of id
         var elem = $(this).attr("id") -1; //this is modified id to table elements
     var imageurl = $('.fadein img:eq('+elem+')').attr('src');
     alert( 'the no. '+id +' have url ' + imageurl);

 });
});
```

here is the example
http://jsfiddle.net/CzmTA/3/

and remember the position of element in jquery is an array and it starts from 0 not 1
i think this should work

Comment: thanks for help) but i need to get id by click on the list items (<li> tags), not images. var clickId = this.id; clickId - is the id of the clicked element. var n = clickId - 1; n - is the id for the image . For example i clicked on the first item, and get id for him 1, further i get id for image, it's variable n, and get the url for the first image. My problem in this line var imageurl = $(".fadein img:eq(" + n + ")").attr("src"); specifically in this $(".fadein img:eq(" + n + ")").

Comment: in your code you ve got wrong var n it should look like this `var n = $(this).attr("id")` and this `if (e.which === 1)` is unnecessary